# VIM Search - FuzzyFinder to search specific file

Tags: php, search, vim, macvim

I'm newbie at VIM using it as IDE. I'm trying to figure how to open in an easy way files within my "project".

I have this configurations in my .vimrc file:

```
colorscheme Tomorrow-Night
" nocompatible has to be the first of all ( use the real vimpower )
set nocompatible

" backup rules
set backup " enable backup files (.txt~)
set undofile " enable persistent undo

silent execute '!mkdir -p $HOME/.vim/tmp/backup'
set backupdir=$HOME/.vim/tmp/backup " where to store backup
silent execute '!mkdir -p $HOME/.vim/tmp/swap'
set directory=$HOME/.vim/tmp/swap " where to store swap
silent execute '!mkdir -p $HOME/.vim/tmp/views'
set viewdir=$HOME/.vim/tmp/views " where to store view
silent execute '!mkdir -p $HOME/.vim/tmp/undo'
set undodir=$HOME/.vim/tmp/undo " where to store undo 

" syntax
syntax on " enable syntax highlighting
" filetype
filetype on " enable filetype detection
filetype plugin on " enable filetype plugins
filetype indent on " enable filetype indentation

" tabstop settings
set tabstop=4 " a tab found in a file will be represented with 4 columns
set softtabstop=4 " when in insert mode <tab> is pressed move 4 columns
set shiftwidth=4 " indentation is 4 columns

" show linenumbers
set number

" Documentation configuration
let g:pdv_cfg_Author = 'Abraham Cruz <abrahamsustaita@gmail.com>'

" Autocompletition
" Complete options (disable preview scratch window)
set completeopt = menu,menuone,longest
" Limit popup menu height
set pumheight = 15

" SuperTab option for context aware completion
let g:SuperTabDefaultCompletionType = "context"
let g:SuperTabNoCompleteAfter = ['^', ',', '\s']        
let g:SuperTabMappingForward = '<c-space>'
let g:SuperTabMappingBackward = '<s-c-space>'

" Disable auto popup, use <Tab> to autocomplete
" let g:clang_complete_auto = 0
" Show clang errors in the quickfix window
let g:clang_complete_copen = 1

" TagBar Lint
let g:tagbar_phpctags_memory_limit = '512M'

" Upload on save if the project is configured to do so
autocmd BufWritePost * :call SyncUploadFile()

" Open each buffer in its own tab
:au BufAdd,BufNewFile * nested tab sball
```

So every new buffer is opened in a new tab.

I know if I do:

```
:e libra*/Core/Sess*/Ob*
```

for instance, it will open the file `library/Core/Session/Object.php` But the problem is if I make one mistake, instead of open the file, it will open a new Buffer with the name `libra*/Core/Sess*/Ob*` (supposing the file does not exists). Also, I don't like to be writing every time all the `/` so will be better to just do:

```
:e libr*Cor*Sess*Obj*.php
```

But it will open a new buffer with that name (`libr*Cor*Sess*Obj*.php`), instead of opening the file...

I came to know also that I can do:

```
:fin libra(press tab here)
```

And it will autocomplete... but the problem here is it will show (for this example) `:find libexslt/` and I know for sure that folder is not within the folder I'm. Actually, here is an screenshot of the folders I have there:

[image: Folders on working folder]

So as you can see, I have no libexslt there... so I don't know where it is getting that info from...

Is there any way to open a file easily? In this example, I know the file is Session/Object.php so could I do something like:

```
:fin *Sessi*Obj*php
```

? Also, I know the file has inside the declaration:

```
<?php
class Core_Session_Object
```

Or, another example,

```
<?php
namespace Core\Session;
class Object
```

Can I do something like:

```
:vimgrep /class*Core_Session_Object/ *.php
:vimgrep /name*Core*Sess*Obj/ *.php
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use tab-completion for `:edit` and `:find` but the default mechanism is not very user-friendly. The "wildmenu" is a very nice feature that makes the whole process *a lot* easier. Enable it with:

```
:set wildmenu
```

and take a look at the following sections of the documentation:

```
:help wildmenu
:help wildmode
:help wildignore
:help wildignorecase
```

---

The `**` wildcard allows you to recurse through subdirectories so you can do:

```
:e **/obj*ph<Tab>
```

---

The behavior of `:find` depends on the value of the `path` option whose default value is not very useful if you don't write C.

Set it to this much more useful generic value to recurse through subdirectories:

```
:set path=.,**
```

---

With the settings above, you should be able to open your file with:

```
:e **/obj*ph<Tab>
```

or:

```
:find obj*ph<Tab>
```

---

Note that opening a file to access a method or some other symbol is not very efficient, whether you use clever commands/mappings or not. Tag-jumping is *a much more efficient* method. You'll need a symbol "database", usually crated before the search, for that, though.

See these sections of the documentation:

```
:help tags
:help ctags
:help cscope
```

And `:h include-search` for a lightweight variant.

Using `:vimgrep` or `:grep` can also serve your needs but I'd suggest you take a look at the faster [ack](http://beyondgrep.com/) and [ag](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher).

---

Here is a cleaned up version of your `vimrc` with the relevant options added:

```
filetype plugin indent on
syntax on

colorscheme Tomorrow-Night

set wildmenu

set path=./**

set backup
set undofile

silent execute '!mkdir -p $HOME/.vim/tmp/backup'
set backupdir=$HOME/.vim/tmp/backup " where to store backup
silent execute '!mkdir -p $HOME/.vim/tmp/swap'
set directory=$HOME/.vim/tmp/swap " where to store swap
silent execute '!mkdir -p $HOME/.vim/tmp/views'
set viewdir=$HOME/.vim/tmp/views " where to store view
silent execute '!mkdir -p $HOME/.vim/tmp/undo'
set undodir=$HOME/.vim/tmp/undo " where to store undo

set tabstop=4
set softtabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4

set number

set completeopt = menu,menuone,longest
set pumheight = 15

augroup VIMRC
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufWritePost * :call SyncUploadFile()
    autocmd BufAdd,BufNewFile * nested tab sball
augroup END

let g:pdv_cfg_Author = 'Abraham Cruz <abrahamsustaita@gmail.com>'

let g:SuperTabDefaultCompletionType = "context"
let g:SuperTabNoCompleteAfter = ['^', ',', '\s']
let g:SuperTabMappingForward = '<c-space>'
let g:SuperTabMappingBackward = '<s-c-space>'

let g:clang_complete_copen = 1

let g:tagbar_phpctags_memory_limit = '512M'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man! It helped me a lot. About the database, I'm trying to use ctag, but I really don't like the way it behaves...

Answer (score 0):

It's always good to learn pure Vim methods for navigating files, which makes romainl's answer really good.

There are also a couple of plugins that provide the fuzzy-finder feature.

1. [Ctrl-p plugin](http://kien.github.io/ctrlp.vim/)
2. [Command-t plugin](https://github.com/wincent/Command-T)

That said, I've had Ctrl-p installed for a long time, but I rarely use it because I just don't need it.